# How do you interpret negative levels in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to gain a deeper understanding of how Mathematica expressions are represented internally, and am puzzled by the logic of the `Level` command in Mathematica.  If we have the following input:

```
In[1]:= a = z*Sin[x + y] + z1*Cos[x1 + y1]

Out[1]= z1 Cos[x1 + y1] + z Sin[x + y]

In[2]:= FullForm[a]

Out[2]= Plus[Times[z1,Cos[Plus[x1,y1]]],Times[z,Sin[Plus[x,y]]]]

In[3]:= TreeForm[a]
```

We get the following tree:

[image: tree form of expression a, above]

If we ask Mathematica to return Level 4 only, we get:

```
In[4]:= Level[a,{4}]
Out[4]= {x1,y1,x,y}
```

I understand that we are 4 levels down from the "stem" (the Plus operator at Level 0).  In fact, I think I understand that positive indexes are always in relation to the stem position of the tree.  (I hope I'm correct about that??)

In contrast, when you ask for a negative level, there is no common reference point (like the stem above), because different branches of the tree are of varying lengths.  So, if you ask Mathematica to provide only Level -1, we get:

```
In[6]:= Level[a,{-1}]
Out[6]= {z1,x1,y1,z,x,y}
```

I was surprised by this output, when I had guessed that I should get back `{x1, y1, x, y}` (without `z1` & `z`).  But ok, if I try to understand this, I take -1 to mean "the end of each branch".  If this is so, then I would expect `Level[a,{-2}]` to return:

```
{z1*Cos[x1+y1],z*Sin[x+y],x1+y1,x+y}
```

But, this is not what I get back, Mathematica yields:

```
In[8]:= Level[a,{-2}]
Out[8]= {x1+y1,x+y}
```

So, now I am confused, and don't see a consistent way of understanding the output of negative levels.

Is there a consistent, easier way of understanding this topic?  Is there a certain "correct" way I should be reading the structure of the tree?

Sorry for the "long-winded question", but I hope you understand what I am asking.

Answer (score 14):

If you look at the [docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Level.html), they say:

> A negative level -n consists of all parts of expr with depth n.

So negative levels are not counted from a reference point, but are defined based on the depth of subexpressions.  `z1*Cos[x1+y1]` is of depth 4, so it's not returned when you ask for `Level[..., {-2}]`.

Comment: Concise and clear - +1. I'd add to this, that level specs without curly braces (like in `Level[expr, -d ]` describe all sub-expressions of depth *at least* `d`, being equivalent to `Level[expr, {1, -d}]`. This allows us to combine positive and negative levels in non-trivial ways. For example, this: `Level[a,{2,-2}]` will return only sub-expressions on levels below and including level `2`, *and* having depth *at least* `2`.